# Bean creation issue: The bean 'xyz', defined in class path resource could not be registered

Tags: spring-boot

I am facing an issue while creating a bean. I tried resolving the error by making `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` but I want to know why this error has occured.

Exception occurred. please refer bellow error for reference.

```
Description:

The bean 'configProvider', defined in class path resource 
[com/fidel/fixadaptor/config/BeanConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has 
already been defined in file [D:\Swapnil\Kovacap\CODE\fix-adaptor- 
Ver1.1\target\classes\com\fidel\fixadaptor\config\ConfigProvider.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean- 
definition-overriding=true
```

**Bean Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.fidel.fixadaptor")
public class BeanConfig {

    /** The destination. */
    private AdaptorDestination destination;

    private ConfigProvider configProvider;

    /**
     * Config provider.
     *
     * @return the config provider
     */

    @Bean
    public ConfigProvider configProvider() {
        if (configProvider == null) {
            configProvider = new ConfigProvider();
        }
        return configProvider;
        }

    /**
    * Recovery.
    *
    * @return the recovery
    */

    @Bean
    public Recovery recovery() {
        return new RecoveryManager(configProvider());
    }
 }
```

**ConfigProvider Class**

```
@Component
public class ConfigProvider {

    private HashMap<String, String> configMap;

    @Autowired
    private FixUtils fixUtils;

    /**
     * @param activeProfile
     * @param connectionType
     * @return
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getConfig(String activeProfile, String connectionType) {
        String file = fixUtils.getConfigFile(connectionType, activeProfile);
        File cfgFile = new File(file);
        configMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(cfgFile);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String keyValue = sc.nextLine();
                String keys[] = keyValue.split("=");
                configMap.put(keys[0], keys[1]);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return configMap;
    }

}
```

Please help me out to understand why it is happening, for any other info comment me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Classes annotated with Spring's `@Component` anotation are managed automatically by the spring bean container, i.e: Spring will create a single instance itself, and inject it wherever needed. The problem is that you are exposing another bean manually, and so it happens that this creates ambiguity and the framework is not able to determine which one to inject where.

The solution is to remove your declaration of the bean and let spring do what was made for.

Comment: I am manually doing this cause I want to provide that bean as an argument to `@Bean
    public Recovery recovery() {
        return new RecoveryManager(configProvider());
    }`  recovery bean

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to accomplish.Why do you want to do it manually when spring can do it for you?

Comment: Just suggest me if ill remove configProvider() then how recoveryManager() will get it